# How to redirect to a new Component (Page) once the user is authenticated with Auth0 on React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, react-router, auth0

-I am using Auth0 to authentication in react, I was wondering how can I redirect once the user is authenticated to a new component.

-I am not using react-router-dom , Do I need it ?

-This image have the main part, "onClick={()=>loginWithRedirect()" :
[There is the "loginWithRedirect()" I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KugIH.png)

Here is my code:

```
import {Fragment} from "react";
import "../css/AppLightMode.css";
import ButtonMode from "./ButtonMode";

//Importamos Auth0
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import LogoutButton from "./Logout";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import AppPage from "./AppPage.js";


const MainPageLightMode = ()=>{

const {loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated} = useAuth0();
return (

  <Fragment>
  <header className="container">

    <ButtonMode/>
  
    <div className="header-img row"> 
      
      <div className="left seven columns image u-max-full-width">
        
      </div>

      <div className="right five columns">
        <h1>Learn languages with music</h1>
        <p>Learn a new language with a video music and the lyrics in your native language and the language you are learning on </p>
       
        <div className="div-btn">
          {isAuthenticated ? <>
          <Profile/>
          <LogoutButton/>
          </> 
          : <a className="btn-neu-for-lm btn-login btn " onClick={()=>loginWithRedirect() }><span> Login</span></a>}
          
          <a className="btn-neu-for-lm btn-instructions btn" href="#" ><span>Instructions</span></a>
       
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </header>

  </Fragment>


  )
}

export default MainPageLightMode;
```

Comment: Provide your ```loginWithRedirect``` function here

Comment: It is provided by Auth0, I did not make it. I solved it anyways, thank you man ! @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV